# How to style horizontally and vertically?

Tags: html, css, vuejs3

```html
<div class="flex-container">
        
        <div class="flex-row">

            <li class="org-li" v-for="o in orgs">
                <div class="flex-item">
                    <button v-b-modal.link_printer @click="click_org(o.id)" class="org-btn">
                        <img class="org-img" :src="`http://localhost:8080/orgs/org_pictures/${o.img}`" alt=""/>
                    </button>
                </div>
        
                <li class="printer-li" v-for="p in printers[o.id]">
                    <div class="flex-item">
                        <button variant="outline-primary" class="printer-btn" v-bind:org_id="`${o.id}`" v-bind:printer_id="`${p.id}`" @click="onClick(o.id, p.id, p.serial_number)" >
                            <img class="printer-img" :src="`http://localhost:8080/printers/printer_pictures/${p.img}`" alt=""/>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </li>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I want the org-img to be 55px x 55px and I want the printer-img to be 25px x 25px. Each org-btn and printer-btn should be centered vertically on the screen.

I have been having difficulties with the printer-img being slightly offset from being vertically aligned.

Comment: which css framework are you using? want to replicate on locally, or can you provide codesandbox or similar demo

Answer (score 0):

you can do it that way. This adds the CSS styles to your component's  block. The .org-img and .printer-img styles will define the width and height of the images, and the .flex-item style will center the buttons within the div elements that contain them. And the .flex-container will wrap the content inside on overflow.
You can make adjustments as needed to match your component's specific structure and class naming.

```
<template>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <li class="org-li" v-for="o in orgs">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <button v-b-modal.link_printer @click="click_org(o.id)" class="org-btn">
            <img class="org-img" :src="`http://localhost:8080/orgs/org_pictures/${o.img}`" alt=""/>
          </button>
        </div>
        
        <li class="printer-li" v-for="p in printers[o.id]">
          <div class="flex-item">
            <button variant="outline-primary" class="printer-btn" v-bind:org_id="`${o.id}`" v-bind:printer_id="`${p.id}`" @click="onClick(o.id, p.id, p.serial_number)" >
              <img class="printer-img" :src="`http://localhost:8080/printers/printer_pictures/${p.img}`" alt=""/>
            </button>
          </div>
        </li>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  .org-img {
      width: 55px;
      height: 55px;
  }

  .printer-img {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
  }

  .flex-item {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
  }
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
</style>
```